# Can i create single plugin and build for outlook add-in and gmail addons in the same time?

Tags: plugins, outlook-addin, gmail-addons

I have a gmail addons for my app and i want to make anothor one for outlook so I wants to know if there is a tool to create juste one application (based on JS) and run it in two platforms ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. See [Outlook add-ins overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/) for more information.